# How to set a navigation bar in clear / transparent background in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to figure out how to write a code for a custom navigation bar to display clear / transparent bar not "white" bar. See this screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

init() {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
         ZStack {
              Color(.lightGray).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack() {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Hello").foregroundColor(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("First View"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       ContentView()
    
 }
}
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with it?

Comment: This seems like a bug in SwiftUI. I'm running Xcode Version 11.2 beta (11B41) w/ iOS 13.1.2 and when I preview the `ContentView` it renders as per your screenshot example. However when I deploy to iPhone it renders differently. - Xcode Preview: https://imgur.com/xkPCtgu and iPhone: https://imgur.com/a/qs21wfw.

Comment: @fuzz I thought it was a bug but it is not. You can see hightech's answer here. It is working so well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried to run your code on my Xcode. I received the same results like yours. I found a good solution to fix this issue. You just need to add a few lines of code into your `init()`. Here is the solution:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

     init() {

          UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
          UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
          UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
          UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .clear
          UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
     }

     var body: some View {

          NavigationView {
              ZStack {
                  Color(.lightGray).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                  VStack() {
                      Spacer()
                      Text("Hello").foregroundColor(.white)
                      Spacer()
                  }
             }
              .navigationBarTitle(Text("First View"), displayMode: .inline)
          }
       }
    }

   struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
          static var previews: some View {
             ContentView()

          }
    }
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: If a search brought you here and you are not using Swift UI, then do the same as hightech's answer in viewWillAppear and replace UINavigationBar.appearance() with self.navigationController?.navigationBar

Comment: What are the default values for the navigation bar if you need to restore the bar back to it's default aesthetic?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 16 you can just use `.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)` for content of ether `NavigationView` or `NavigationStack` to achieve clear background no matter what.

But for your particular case the NavBar background should be already transparent by default - just remove the `init()`.

If you need to some particular background for NavBar, consider using a combination of modifiers that apply `ShapeStyle` and visibility to it, i.e.:

```
    NavigationView {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .toolbarBackground(.red, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle(Text("Title"))
    }
```