# UINavigationBar Transparent

Tags: swiftui, autolayout

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with a custom back button in SwiftUI, but I didn't find a way to make the navigation transparent or clear in the landscape, how does someone already make a project with that transparent?[image: landscape mode]

here is my code

```
   import SwiftUI

 struct LoginView: View {
     @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

var backButton : some View { Button(action: {
       self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
       }) {
           HStack {
           Image("Backarrow") // BackButton Image
               .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
               .foregroundColor(.white)
               Text(" Back")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)//translated Back button title
           }
       }
   }

var topImage:some View{
        Image("header2")
            .resizable()
            .overlay( ImageOverlay() , alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.black)
}

var usernameTextField:some View{
    
        HStack{
            TextField("", text: $LoginViewM.username)
                .placeholder(Text("Phone number, username or email").padding().foregroundColor(.white), show: LoginViewM.password.isEmpty)
                .background(Color.black)
            Image("menuCloseSmall")
                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 14))
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
         .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", fixedSize: 16.4))
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
       
    
   }

var errorUsernameLabel:some View{
    VStack{
        Text("    Hey you, no user found. Make sure you’ve provided the ")
            .lineLimit(1)
           Text("correct information.")
    }
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .foregroundColor(.redBlueParrot)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12.1))
   

}

var passwordTextField:some View{
    HStack{
        TextField("Password", text: $LoginViewM.password)
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", fixedSize: 16.4))
            .padding(.bottom)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .placeholder(Text("Password").padding().foregroundColor(.white), show: LoginViewM.username.isEmpty)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            .background(Color.black)
        Image("editShow")
            .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 14))
    }
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3))
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
    
}

var errorPasswordLabel:some View{
    VStack{
        Text("      Incorrect password for \(LoginViewM.password). Please try again.")
    }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        .foregroundColor(.redBlueParrot)
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12.1))
}
var buttonLogin:some View{
    
    NavigationLink(
        destination: Text("Hola"),
        label: {
            Text("Login")
        })            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 16))
        .foregroundColor(Color.ligthGray)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: 174, maxWidth: 174, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: 42,      maxHeight: 42, alignment: .center)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1.5))
        
    
}

var textInBottom:some View{
    
    HStack(spacing:5){
        Text("Forgot")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
        Button("password"){
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
        Text("or")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
        Button("username"){
            
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
    }
    .padding()
}

@ObservedObject  var LoginViewM:LoginViewModel

var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader{ geometry in
        
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                topImage
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height * 0.35)
                    
                VStack(spacing:17){
                    usernameTextField
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.90, height: geometry.size.height*0.05)
                    errorUsernameLabel
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.90,height: geometry.size.height*0.04, alignment: .center)
                    
                    passwordTextField
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.90, height: geometry.size.height*0.05)
                
                    errorPasswordLabel
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height*0.02, alignment: .center)
                    
                }.frame( height: geometry.size.height * 0.40)
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    buttonLogin
                    textInBottom
                }
            
                
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)

            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            .background(Color.black)
        }
        
        
        .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .background(Color.black)
    }
    .onAppear{
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
         UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
         UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
         UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
       
}



 }
```

I already tried to change the appearance of the navigation but it did not work, any other ideas that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a navigation bar in clear / transparent background in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383318/how-to-set-a-navigation-bar-in-clear-transparent-background-in-swiftui)

Comment: I had already read that question, I really did the same but it did not work for me, I don't know if it is something in my code or something like that but the same in it.