# Swiftui List Navigation Bar transparent

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to make the navigation bar transparent, like in the first image

[image]

[image]

The difference is that the `test` view is wrapped inside a `NavigationView` but I can't use that on the second view (contact & faq).

The `test` view is like a leaf, there's no more navigation from it.
But from the `contact & FAQ` view, there's more navigation to be done.

```
Settings
| -Contact & FAQ
      | - FAQ
           | - question1
           | - question2
```

If i wrap the list in `NavigationView` on  both `Contact & FAQ` and `FAQ`, i get a double navigation bar
[image]

```
Settings View

NavigationView {
            List {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContactView()) {
                        
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: "questionmark.bubble")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.primaryColor)
                            Text("Contact & FAQ")
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

```
Contact & FAQ View

List {            
            Section {
                NavigationLink(destination: FAQListView()) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "questionmark.diamond")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.primaryColor)
                        Text("FAQ")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.primaryBLReversed)
                    }
                }
    }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .background(Color.primaryBackground)
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 18.37))
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(.....)
        .background(Color.primaryBackground)
        .padding(.top, 10)
```

```
FAQ List View

List {
            ForEach(....)
            .padding(.top, 20)
            .background(Color.primaryBackground)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
     }
        .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 18.37))
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(....)
        .background(Color.primaryBackground)
        .padding(.top, 10)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make SwiftUI navigation bar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616430/make-swiftui-navigation-bar-transparent)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383318/how-to-set-a-navigation-bar-in-clear-transparent-background-in-swiftui

Comment: No, sorry. I'm talking about a list view, not navigation view. I've tried what they said in the posts but it's not wokring for me

Comment: Then share more code (and not as screenshots). Because as it currently reads, your question (and pictures) are about navigation bar (List contains navigation link, but it's not the one setting a style for navigation bar). List background, btw, also has a bunch of solutions and workarounds, if this is what you are asking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517904/how-do-i-modify-the-background-color-of-a-list-in-swiftui

Comment: I've added some pieces of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some trial and error this is are the final modifier that i've added to the list

```
.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 18.37))
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

The culprit was that `.padding(.top, 10)` which was giving the toolbar a color. Now that i've removed it, it doesn't show a color anymore, except the list goes behind the toolbar, for which i use the `.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)` but this is for ios 16+